# Почему KeyEvent.VK_PLUS не работает в Java?

Tags: java, swing

У меня есть `JMenuItem`, а у `JMenuItem` есть Слушатель. Если я нажму на `JMenuItem`, метод заработает. Также ещё есть `JTextArea` у которого стоит слушатель клавиш.
Если я нажму на клавиатуре ctrl + Plus то метод работать не будет. Также есть комбинация клавиш ctrl + Minus которая работает.

В чём проблема?

Код:

```
 jta.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

     }

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_PLUS && e.isControlDown()) {
             zoomplus();
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

     }

 });
```

PS: вставил только тот кусок кода который не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто - Вы нажимаете не `ctrl + "+"`, а `ctrl + "="`

(как Вы знаете, что бы была кнопка `+`, надо нажать `shift`)

---

Что бы исправить эту ошибку, Вым следует заменять `KeyEvent.VK_PLUS` на `KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS`:

```java
    ...

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS && e.isControlDown()) {
            zoomplus();
        }
    }

    ...
```